# Фильтр-поиск товаров на yii

Tags: поиск, php, yii

Как организовать фильтр-поиск товаров на `yii`? Есть ли для этого уже какие-то готовые инструменты, чтобы не городить велосипеды?

Answer (score 1):

Возможно [CGridView](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView) пригодится.

На [Хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/156251/) расписывали расширение его функционала

Answer (score 0):

Всякого рода поиски правильно было бы делать с помощью поисковых движков (Sphinx, Zend_Search_Lucene и прочее). Иначе придется делать велосипед, т.к. поиск это попытка угадать, что хочет юзер.

Comment: мне не нужен полнотекстовый поиск. нужен фильтр, который уже реализован, например в CGridView, если я правильно понял

Comment: Тогда используя CDbCriteria, это сделать очень просто. Если сами не справитесь могу обновить свой ответ описав это с примерами. как раз этим сейчас занимаюсь.

Comment: спасибо, надеюсь справлюсь.